# Criar tabelas em um banco mysql hospedado no Locaweb

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Preciso adicionar uma tabela no meu banco de dados.
Como faço pra adicionar uma tabela a este banco hospedado na locaweb? Tem de ter algum software ou posso subir algum arquivo?

Comment: `create table nome_da_tabela` ?

Comment: Você está com dúvida no script pra criar a tabela ou em como conectar pra poder ter acesso a execução de scripts?

Comment: Mas eu devo colocar no meu arquivo sql pronto e subir pro servidor ou fazer um novo arquivo?

Comment: eu não sei como criar a tabela, já que já uso o banco de dados.

Comment: Então é bom começar por aqui: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Answer (score 3):

Você deve entrar no cPanel do domínio em questão, clicar no ícone referente ao phpMyAdmin e na barra de menu superior clicar na aba SQL. Irá abrir uma área de texto onde você digitará o comando para adicionar uma tabela.

Seguindo esse modelo:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
column_name1 data_type(size),
column_name2 data_type(size),
column_name3 data_type(size),
....
);
```

Um exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)
```

Comment: vou tentar aqui. Obrigada